# Duplicate class android.support.v4.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat

Tags: android-gradle-plugin

In my android app

in app/build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myproject"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 285
        versionName "1.4.285"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

def AAVersion = '4.6.0'

dependencies {
    annotationProcessor "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:$AAVersion"

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'

    implementation "org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:$AAVersion"

    implementation project(':binding')
    implementation project(':cacheservice')       

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

But I get error when build project:

```
> Task :app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.
> 1 exception was raised by workers:
  java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate class android.support.v4.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0) and support-v4-19.0.1.jar (com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.1)
  Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-core-ui:28.0.0) and support-v4-19.0.1.jar (com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.1)
  Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle$Delegate found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-core-ui:28.0.0) and support-v4-19.0.1.jar (com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.1)
  Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle$DelegateProvider found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-core-ui:28.0.0) and support-v4-19.0.1.jar (com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.1)
  Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle$SlideDrawable found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-core-ui:28.0.0) and support-v4-19.0.1.jar (com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.1)
  Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0) and support-v4-19.0.1.jar (com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the list of dependencies and details about each dependency using following commands.

```
gradlew -q app:dependencies

gradlew -q app:dependencyInsight --configuration FLAVORNAMEReleaseCompileClasspath --dependency dependencyNAME

gradlew -q app:dependencyInsight --configuration RanjanReleaseCompileClasspath --dependency com.google.android.libraries.tv:companionlibrary
```

Comment: I try this:  configurations {
        all*.exclude group: 'android.support.v4.app', module: 'classes.jar'
        all*.exclude group: 'android.support.v4.accessibilityservice', module: 'classes.jar'
    }  - but it not help. Same error

Comment: Fix bug by this: android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true in gradle.propeties

Comment: so, using androidx support libraries solved this problem? Good.